# Suma de dos columnas con inner join

Tags: mysql

Buen dia, alguien que pudiera ayudarme, necesito la  suma de cantidades de dos diferentes tablas a traves de un inner join.

Esta es la tabla "inventory_ticket" tiene como foreing key el id de la tabla "inventory_list" esta es fk_inventory

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la tabla "inventory_list" el id de referencia en la tabla anterior es numFile.

Teniendo en cuenta que el 108 se puede encontrar en diferentes ticket, necesito que se identifiquen por el id_ticket.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el query que he intentado:

```
SELECT 
    quantityTicket, 
    i.quantity 
    sum(quantityTicket + i.quantity) 
inner join inventory_list as i on numFile = fk_Inventory 
where id_ticket = 1
```

Me da el siguiente error:

> `#`1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'sum(quantityTicket + i.quantity) inner join inventory_list where
>   id_ticket=1' at line 1

Lo que necesito que se muestre es:

15, sumando  quantity_Ticket de  "inventory_ticket" y quantity de "inventory_list" del id_ticket 1

Comment: Cierto, pero sigue dando error en la consulta.

Comment: Ademas le falta una coma, y definir algun tipo de group by por donde sumar.

Comment: Fernanda, primero te recomendaría ordenar tu consulta antes de hacer la suma, te quedaría algo como esto `SELECT * 
FROM  inventory_ticket it
INNER JOIN inventory_list i ON i.numFile = it.fk_Inventory 
WHERE it.id_ticket = 108`

Comment: Algo asi deberia ser la consulta
SELECT t.quantityTicket, i.quantity 
sum (t.quantityTicket + i.quantity) as SUMA
From inventory_ticket as t 
inner join inventory_list as i on numFile = fk_Inventory where t.id_ticket = 108
Order By SUMA

Comment: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(t.quantityTicket + i.quantity) as SUMA From inventory_ticket as t inner join in' at line 1` 

Gracias por tu ayuda, pero me sale el siguiente error, ademas como el 108 se puede encontrar en mas tickets, prefiero que la suma sea donde el id_ticket = 1

Comment: No se entiende bien lo que quieres. En el planteamiento inicial dices que te interesa el `id_ticket=108` y luego en tu último comentario dices que te interesa el `id_ticket=1`. La consulta que propone @JuanPablo da error porque ha reproducido el mismo error inicial que tenías: no hay una coma de separación entre `i.quantity sum (t.quantityTicket + i.quantity)`, si lo pones así no dará error: **`i.quantity, sum (t.quantityTicket + i.quantity)`**

Comment: Me parece que el error es mas grande de lo que pensas. Mas alla de que la consulta es totalmente invalida, y estamos tratando de arreglarla al voleo, te recomendaria que ademas de esos dos datos, que no son los unicos que hay, muestres algunos mas, y el resultado esperado, con los valores esperados segun los datos que mostras

Comment: ¿Siempre habrá una sola fila en cada tabla? si hay más de una, sugiero que muestres un conjunto de datos con varias filas en cada tabla y cuál es el resultado que esperas obtener. Por ahora, con el planteamiento que haces, bastaría con que dejes de llamar a la función `sum`.